# 'nur noch ganz'

Tags: translation

I am having difficulty understanding this sentence from a [weather report on FAZ](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/gesellschaft/wetter-in-deutschland-bis-zu-38-grad-am-wochenende-16882858.html).

> Am Sonntag wird die 30 Grad Marke wohl **nur noch ganz** im Osten
> **angerissen**.

I am struggling with the bold parts.

1. Does *nur noch ganz im Osten* mean *only in the East*, or *in all of the East*?
2. Does *angerissen* mean the 30 degree mark will be *ripped through* or will be *touched*? Both are listed in dictionaries.

Comment: It's _in the far east_ and _touched_ in your example.

Comment: *ganz* belongs to *im Osten*, not to *nur noch*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*anreißen* in this context means "barely reached".

Nur ganz im Osten means "only in the very east".

> Am Sonntag wird die 30 Grad Marke wohl **nur** *noch* **ganz** im Osten angerissen.

Thus translates to

> **Only** in **the very** east temperatures of 30 degress will *still* be reached on sunday.

Comment: Your subdivision is still misleading. The relevant expressions are "nur noch X" (*only X remaining*) and "ganz im Osten" (*in the Easternmost parts*).

Comment: I disagree. "Nur ganz im Osten" is different than "Nur noch ganz im Osten". The noch implies that it has been reached before. That's why I translated this with stil. @KilianFoth